# Why cache is purged after a short time

Tags: doctrine, twig

I'm trying to reduce my symfony webpage loading time by using the `cache` tag in template and using doctrine cache in repository, like this :

In TWIG :

```php
{% cache "navbar;v1;" ~ last_updated_at %}
{# loops, conditions and HTML ...#}
{% endcache %}
```

In REPOSITORY

```php
...
return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->complexQuery...
    ->getQuery()
    ->setHint(Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true)
    ->useResultCache(true, 14400)              
    ->getResult();
```

The first time I load the page I have a high load time and many SQL queries :
[image]
[image]

Then I refresh the page and it's much better :
[image]
[image]

I keep this tab open, I move to another task for let's say 15mn then I go back to that page and refresh it : I have something similar to the first screenshot :(

Cache seems to be purged or browser seems to ask a fresh version of the page ! Why the cache is acting like this ? Knowing data was not updated and cache should not be purged in that case !

Comment: Did you try to specify the TTL (time-to-live) in the template as well? E.g. `{% cache "cache key" ttl(300) %}` (300 = 300 seconds) - [source](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/cache.html)

Comment: No ttl since I'm using a timestamp as explained in the doc : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/cache.html ``For instance, I would use {% cache "blog_post;v1;" ~ post.id ~ ";" ~
post.updated_at %} to cache a blog content template fragment ...``

Comment: Well you I'd try to add the TTL to that fragment though, `% cache "blog_post;v1;" ~ post.id ~ ";" ~ post.updated_at  ttl(14400) %}`. The first part is just to create an unique key to cache the content. I was not able to find the default TTL in the source code, but I guess 15min could be the default

Comment: I tested with `ttl(3600)` : after 30mn I went back to the tab, it was blank and Firefox automatically refreshed it : cache was purged :(

Comment: even after 15mn the cache was purged (after manual refresh)